# redirect bash output and error for all commands

Tags: linux, bash, output, dev-null

How to redirect all commands executed on the bash to /dev/null ?

It's obvious that for a command we have to do:

```
command > /dev/null  2>&1
```

How about all commands that will be executed further on ?

Answer (score 5):

Simply start a new shell:

```
bash >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Now you can type commands *blind* :) If you want to leave that mode type: `exit`

But typing commands blind will normally not what you want. So I would suggest to create a text file like `script.sh`, place your commands in it:

```
command1 foo 
command2 bar
```

and than execute it using:

```
bash script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The ouput of all commands in that script will be redirected to /dev/null now

Comment: I got this:
[1] 13407
bash: 2: No such file or directory
1: command not found
[1]+  Exit 127                bash 2 > /dev/null

Comment: try `/usr/bin/bash` instead of `bash`. Btw, which system are you using?

Comment: yeah I do have it, but he doesn't recognize the 2 and the 1

Comment: Type it by your own hands no paste and copy

Comment: yes it worked. But if I want to redirect only the error output ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `exec` without a command:

```
exec > /dev/null 2>&1
```

As hex2mgl pointed out, if you do this in an interactive shell, you won't even see your prompt anymore, as the shell prints that to standard error. I assume this is intended for a script, as it doesn't make a lot of sense to ignore all output from commands run interactively :)

Comment: It's not blocked; all output (both standard output and standard error, which includes your prompt) has been redirected to `/dev/null`, as requested.

Comment: `exec 2>/dev/null`. But that will still redirect your typing and the prompt to `/dev/null`/.

Answer (score 0):

for scripting or other practical purpose, grouping the command is a nice solution. check http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Compound-Commands.html  It says specifically `Any redirections (see Redirections) associated with a compound command apply to all commands within that compound command unless explicitly overridden.`